# Setting caret position in Sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have a plugin which opens a file and then when loaded calls

`view.run_command("goto_line", {"line": item["Line"]})`

In the gutter in the left hand side it seems to go to that line as its line number is highlighted in the gutter however, there is no caret in that file. Is there someway to get the caret to start blinking on that line too?

**UPDATE:** I have noticed if the file is already opened the caret appears on that line so its only when you open a closed file that the caret is not there

Comment: You could always mess with the selections manually with `view.sel`.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Story:**

I ran into this issue far too many times while developing a plugin. Here's the line that did it for me:

`self.view.window().open_file("{0}:{1}:{2}".format(full_file_path, line_num, 0), sublime.ENCODED_POSITION)`

This will open `full_file_path` and jump to `line_num`, even if the file is not already opened.

**Long Story:**

The first few words of this line will depend on what your command class inherits from. For my purposes, this line is placed in a class that extends `sublime_plugin.TextCommand`. Classes that extend `sublime_plugin.TextCommand` do not have a direct way of communicating with the `window`. Instead, they reference `window` as a method of the `view` object, which is native to `sublime_plugin.TextCommand`s. (The method returns a reference to the `window` object).

If this line were to be placed in a class that extends `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand`, it would need to be modified as such:

`self.window.open_file("{0}:{1}:{2}".format(full_file_path, line_num, 0), sublime.ENCODED_POSITION)`

Notice: no `view` object, and the parentheses following `window` are omitted because we're no longer referencing it through a method of `view`.

As seen [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View), the window() method "returns a reference to the window containing the view," thus allowing us access to [these methods](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window) even though we're not inhereiting directly from `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand`.

Comment: Weirdly doesn't seem consistent though. Worked first time and after that I see the same behaviour as in the original question

Comment: Things working first time only often has to do with variables not getting cleared. Everything's a-okay with a fresh slate (i.e. first run), but without proper cleanup after that run, things can get hairy.

Simple test: close and open Sublime and try running again. Restarting the software clears most "first-run-only" problems. From there, it gets easier to zero in on the error.

Comment: Here's a gist, I dont think its variables etc https://gist.github.com/jchannon/1d856033558e7f58b006

Comment: Ah I see - the line I mentioned isn't meant to be assigned to a variable. Try simply running it without the `v = ` prefix. Also, don't forget the line_num argument!

Comment: yeah tried that before i put it out to a variable :(

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your `filename` variable look like? Print its contents...

Comment: I've changed it back to yours and it looks like this - https://gist.github.com/jchannon/1d856033558e7f58b006#file-stackoverflow-py . The file is opened and the status bar says Line 22, Column 5 its just the caret isnt blinking

Comment: Ohh okay, this *could* very well not be the case, or even matter, but humor me:

The "magic line" I gave (in my context) is meant to take `filename` **without** line and column on the end. `filename`, in your case, should be `/Users/jonathanchannon/Projects/MyNancyApp/HomeModule.cs` - with line number given separately. But maybe your notation should work just as well and something else is causing it to fail.

Maybe [this gist](https://gist.github.com/A-Dean/af50ee3b7098d353e7f5) will help?

Comment: Thats what my code is doing its passing in the line and column as part of the format string